# Enviar variable $_SESSION[''] por Ajax para cargar dataTable

Tags: ajax, datatables, session

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se cargar al ingresar a la pagina

```
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="js/data.js"></script>  

    <table id="tabla" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Folio</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Edad</th>                   
                        <th>CURP</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>                 
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>                   
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

se cargan todos lo registros de una tabla pero quiero que se cargen solo los registros ingresados por el usuario actual, para esto quiero usar una variable de sesion

> $_SESSION['idUser']

La cual quiero enviar por ajax y recibirla en el archivo action.php, todo esto al ingresar a la pagina sin seleccionar un boton o un selector como normalmente lo he hecho, espero me puedan apoyar de antemano gracias!

Este es el Archivo data.js donde declaro la variables y la envio en el data pero no realiza nada, reviso en la consola del navegador y no muestra ningun error.

```js
var idUser = '<?php echo $_SESSION['idUser']; ?>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var employeeData = $('#tabla').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "lengthChange": false,
            "processing":true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "order":[],
            "ajax":{
                url:"action.php",
                type:"POST",
                 data:{idUser:idUser, action:cargar},
                dataType:"json"
            },
            "columnDefs":[
                {
                    "targets":[0, 6, 7],
                    "orderable":false,
                },
            ],
            "pageLength": 10
        });
```

```js
require('config.php');

class tabla extends Dbconfig {  
    protected $hostName;
    protected $userName;
    protected $password;
    protected $dbName;
    private $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    private $empTable = 'registros';
    private $dbConnect = false;
    public function __construct(){
        if(!$this->dbConnect){      
            $database = new dbConfig();            
            $this -> hostName = $database -> serverName;
            $this -> userName = $database -> userName;
            $this -> password = $database ->password;
            $this -> dbName = $database -> dbName;          
            $conn = new mysqli($this->hostName, $this->userName, $this->password, $this->dbName);
            $conn->set_charset("utf8");
    
            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Error failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else{
                $this->dbConnect = $conn;
            }
        }
    }
    private function getData($sqlQuery) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
        if(!$result){
            die('Error in query: '. mysqli_error());
        }
        $data= array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $data[]=$row;            
        }
        return $data;
    }
    private function getNumRows($sqlQuery) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
        if(!$result){
            die('Error in query: '. mysqli_error());
        }
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $numRows;
    }
```

```
 Archivo action.php
```

```js
if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'cargar') {
    public function tabla(){        
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->empTable." WHERE idUser=".$this->idUnidad." ";
        if(!empty($_POST["search"]["value"])){
            $sqlQuery .= 'where(id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR nombre LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';          
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR edad LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR curp LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR Fecha LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%") ';          
            $sqlQuery .= ' OR estado LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
        }
        if(!empty($_POST["order"])){
            $sqlQuery .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
        } else {
            $sqlQuery .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
        }
        if($_POST["length"] != -1){
            $sqlQuery .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
        }   
        $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
        
        $sqlQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->empTable." WHERE idUser=".$this->idUser."  ";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery1);
        $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
        
        $Data = array();    
        while( $employee = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {      
            $empRows = array();         
            $empRows[] = $employee['id'];
            $empRows[] = ucfirst($employee['nombre']);
            $empRows[] = $employee['edad'];     
            $empRows[] = $employee['curp']; 
            $empRows[] = $employee['Fecha'];
            $empRows[] = $employee['estado'];                   
            $empRows[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$employee["id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Editar aqui</button>';
            //$empRows[] = '<button type="button" name="ver" id="'.$employee["idPaciente"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" >Ver</button>';
            $empRows[] = '<button type="butto/n" name="delete" id="'.$employee["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" >Delete</button>';
            $Data[] = $empRows;
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
            "recordsTotal"      =>  $numRows,
            "recordsFiltered"   =>  $numRows,
            "data"              =>  $Data
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema?? Has explicado lo *que quieres*, has enseñado lo *que tienes*, pero no has explicado *el problema* o error. El problema es que no sabes hacerlo? Hay muchos tutoriales en google y en youtube, realmente, MUCHOS, ***MUCHÍSIMOS***. Sin un problema concreto, aquí no podemos ayudarte, y en esa pregunta no veo el problema en ninguna parte, ni veo que hayas ***INTENTADO*** hacerlo primero...

Comment: ya lo editado con la explicación de lo que he intentado. Agradecería si me puede compartir una solución o algún tutorial donde pueda entenderlo mejor ya que he buscado y no encuentro lo que necesito. Gracias!

Comment: Una petición AJAX basicamente es un envío de información a un backend, si no podemos ver el código que va a recibir esa petición, cómo podemos saber lo que está mal?? Supongo que en algún sitio tienes un archivo `php` que recibe esa petición, no?? Pues añade ese código también, por favor.